# default business application not working because of H2 db error

Tags: jbpm

On following the steps mentioned in start.jbpm.org:
1. Unzip generated business-application.zip file
2. Go to business-application-service directory
3. Execute launch.sh/bat clean install
4. Open browser at http://localhost:8090

Step 3, which is `./launch.sh clean install` is failing with the below error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Unsupported connection setting "MVCC" [90113-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:622)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.readSettingsFromURL(ConnectionInfo.java:269)
    at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.<init>(ConnectionInfo.java:78)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
```

There have been some recent changes in H2, can someone suggest a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

H2 db removed support for MVCC in 1.4.200 release. Spring-boot 2.2.2 uses same version of H2 DB. To resolve this issue remove "MVCC=true" option from 'spring.datasource.url' in application.properties file.

Comment: I searched for "MVCC=true" in all files and removed it from a total of 6 files. Since i am following the jbpm tutorial i did not want to go too much in detial and somehow this massive removal solved my issue, may be there wasonly one file to change but i did in all so now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Runnon on a mac -- removed "MVCC=true" from src/main/application.properties